# Music Software for making samples

Tags: windows, music

looking for a software for creating a single sample (demo) file of a music albums, i mean:

> load for example *12 tracks* of an album, and auto split each track
>   into a 15 seconds and merge all samples into one mp3 file. i found a
>   web based software to do this but it not automatically.

[Audio Joiner](http://audio-joiner.com/)

Answer (score 1):

### FFMPEG

[FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) can, from the command line, *or a batch file,* grab the first n seconds of a media file, (video or audio), and can merge those splits into a single file, (converting formats if needed).

- Free, gratis & open source **+** *:-)*
- Cross platform including Windows **+** *:-)*
- Can be used to do a lot more **+** *:-)*
- If you are doing this sort of thing regularly you can put it into a batch or script file **+** *:-)*
- Because it is so powerful there are a lot of options to consider **-** *:-(*

### Python + MoviePy

Since actually using FFMPEG can be troublesome due to the shear number of options I often suggest using the [python](https://www.python.org/) library [moviepy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html) which wraps FFMPEG up into a much nicer package. Also:

- Free, gratis & open source  *:-)*
- Cross platform including Windows  *:-)*
- Much easier!  *:-)*

## To install python for windows

*(OS-X and Linux users will most probably already have python installed)*:

1. Go to https://www.python.org/
2. Download the Windows installer
3. Run the installer & make sure that "Add Python to the Path" is selected and that "install pip" is selected.

## To install MoviePy (any platform):

1. Open a terminal Window
2. Type `pip install moviepy` *OS-X & Linux uses will have to prefix this with `sudo`*
3. Wait a few seconds while pip does it's work
4. Type: `py -3-32 -c"from moviepy.editor import *"`

*The last line will get moviepy to download and install FFMPEG where it expects it to be.*

An example moviepy script that will sample the first 15 seconds of all the MP3 files in the current directory would be:

```
import glob, os
from moviepy.editor import *

outname = "sampler.mp3" # Name to save to
tracklist = "tracklist.txt"  # Would provide an ordered list of filenames
duration = 15  # Duration of each clip in seconds

if os.path.exists(tracklist):
    filelist = open(tracklist).read().split('\n')
else:  # No tracklist
    filelist = glob.glob('*.mp3')  # Get a list of the mp3 files 

if outname in filelist: # Make sure we don't include any existing sampler
    filelist.remove(outname)

# Read the clips in
#clips = [AudioFileClip(fname).set_end(duration) for fname in filelist] # No fade out
clips = [AudioFileClip(fname).set_end(15).audio_fadeout(0.5) for fname in filelist] # Half second fade out at the end of each clip

sampler = concatenate_audioclips(clips) # Concatenate
sampler.write_audiofile(outname)  # Save sampler

print('Finished %d tracks written to %s!" % (len(clips), outname))
```

Note that, rather than the fade out in the example above, you could interleave your tracks with one that provides a half seconds silence, *or even a brief needle being dragged noise,* so as to provide a separation between tracks.

If the above is typed into a file called "sampler.py" somewhere on your path, *(such as the python scripts directory),* you can change directory to any that has your MP3 files, *or other formats with small changes to the script above* in and simply type `sampler.py` go generate your sampler.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a free program, [AudioMove](http://softdeluxe.com/AudioMove-248112/) can help, I think. It has batch processing, and has high-quality sample rate conversion to various sample rates.